# Reading in Datasets to Proc Optmodel

Tags: sas, dataset, mathematical-optimization

I have a dataset called **zip5size** that looks like this:

```
zip    district     volume  
22123  springfield  1234
10001  new york     567
20001  dc           8910
20005  dc           1112
10005  new york     1314
```

Where the **zip** and **district** variables are formatted as character and the **volume** variable is formatted as numeric.

I am trying to read the data into my proc optmodel code as follows:

```
proc optmodel;
  set <str> zips;
  set <str> districts;
  num volume;
  read data zip5size into zips=[zip] districts=[district] volume=volume;
quit;
```

I get the following error:

> The target 'districts' must be numeric or string, found a set.

Why does SAS have no problem with the set zips and reading in the zip variable from my dataset, but it has a problem with the set districts and reading in the district variable from my dataset?

Comment: I'm not familiar with proc optmodel, but the "full code" tab here describes a scenario that seems similar to the one you're struggling with: http://support.sas.com/kb/34/830.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `proc optmodel`, `set` is the index-set. For example:

```
data dat; 
   input zip $ district $ volume;
datalines;
22123  springfield  1234
10001  new york      567
20001  dc           8910
20005  dc           1112
10005  new york     1314
;

proc optmodel;
  set <str> model_zips;
  set <str> model_dist;
  num vol_zips{model_zips};
  num vol_dist{model_dist};
  read data dat into model_zips=[zip] vol_zips=volume;
  read data dat into model_dist=[district] vol_dist=volume;
  print vol_zips;
  print vol_dist;
quit;
```

will add to your model to arrays that are indexed by zip code and districts. Here is a [good tutorial](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/63975/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_intromp_sect013.htm) on how to model 1D and 2D variables.